# Retrieve variable from if statement nested in .each function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retrieve a variable from an if statement nested in a jquery `.each` function:

```
var radioAmount;

$('div.amount').each(function() {
  var input = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]');
  if(input.is(':checked')) {
    radioAmount = input.attr('value');
  } else {
    radioAmount = $('#other-amount').val();
  }
});

console.log(radioAmount);
```

I want `radioAmount` to return the input value outside of the `.each` function, but it returns undefined.

I'm sure this should be fairly straight forward and has to do with variable scope but I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

Or maybe this is the wrong approach completely.

Comment: [Your code appears to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/EDBZ8/). Does your radio have a value? Does `#other-amount` exist? Is it a form element of some sort? Does it have a value?

Comment: If `radioAmount` is `undefined`, then there is something else going on that you are not showing us.  Possibilities are that `radioAmount` is not defined in a high enough scope (outside the `.each()` callback) or that you're doing this inside some async function and expecting `radioAmount` to get returned from that.  Also, why use an `.each()` loop if you just want one value for `radioAmount` - that doesn't make sense to me as it can only have one value, but you're iterating over potentially many items and resetting the value over and over.  If you only want one value, then pick one of the divs

Comment: Other possibilities.  `input` doesn't have a `value` attribute or `$('#other-amount')` doesn't exist or doesn't have a value.

Comment: Provide the html mark up ...

Comment: It is possible that you are not getting into `each` handler. Check if `$('div.amount')` returns anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are correct. The markup is a bit of a nightmare that I have no control over. The issue was with `$('#other-amount')` which didn't have a value. You also make a good point about not using `.each()`.

Comment: I copied my comments to an answer so you can indicate that your problem has been figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll move my comments to an answer since guess #5 below seems to have solved it for you:

Without seeing the page and more specifics about the error, I can only guess what things could be causing what you observe.  If `radioAmount` is `undefined`, then there is something else going on that you are not showing us. Possibilities are:

1. That `radioAmount` is not defined in a high enough scope (outside the `.each()` callback)
2. You're doing this inside some async function and expecting `radioAmount` to get returned from that.
3. Perhaps `input` doesn't have a value attribute.
4. Perhaps `$('#other-amount')` doesn't exist.
5. Perhaps `$('#other-amount')` doesn't have a value.

P.S.  Why use a `.each()` loop if you just want one value for `radioAmount` - that doesn't make sense to me as it can only have one value, but you're iterating over potentially many items and resetting the value over and over. If you only want one value, then pick one of the divs

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 number 5 was indeed the issue. Nothing to do with variable scope.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not the variable scope but that `$('#other-amount')` is undefined.

I missed this because I thought it wouldn't matter if a radio input was checked instead.

As suggested in the comments, I have rewritten this without `.each()`:

```
var radioAmount;
var checkedRadio = $('div.amount').find('input[type="radio"]:checked');
if(checkedRadio.length) {
    radioAmount = checkedRadio.attr('value');
} else {
    radioAmount = $('#other-amount').val();
}
console.log(radioAmount);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `filter`. Just `var checkedRadio = $('div.amount').find('input[type="radio"]:checked");` or even `var checkedRadio = $('div.amount input[type="radio"]:checked");`

Comment: @RoToRa the first form of your comment would be faster due to the right to left action of the sizzle behind the selection.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Right. Generally I'd avoid descendant selectors in CSS (and jQuery) due to performance and use child selectors (`>`) where possible instead.

Comment: For jQuery, the `find()` is better in this case due to performance.  In the first example form, it will get the div with amount class, then find *within* that, in the second example, it finds *all* the checked radios, then select those within the div.amount - so potentially a full DOM scan in the first phase rather than just within the div.amount.

Comment: @RoToRa good point, will update my answer. I was using `find()` as I thought this would perform better than the general selector in your second version. Unfortunately due to the html I can't use the child selector `>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var radioToCheck =$('div.amount').find('input[type="radio"]:checked');
var radioAmount = radioToCheck.length ? radioToCheck.val() : $('#other-amount').val();
```

Assumption of `$('#other-amount')` existing and being of an input type with a value.